# Beamer does not restore roman style for emph inside emph

Tags: beamer, emphasis

It seems that `\em` and `\emph` do not alternate between itshape and normal shape.  How can this be restored?

Test case:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{\em abc \emph{def \emph{ghi} jkl} mno}
\end{document}
```

With "article" it works as expected.

This is `beamer 2011/09/12 development version 3.20`.

Comment: Almost certainly this is one of the many things that Till didn't allow for when writing `beamer`, I guess here as it likely use cases are pretty rare.

Comment: Before anything else, remember that a change between rm and it shapes isn't as visible on a presentation as on a paper, that's why `beamer` defines the command `\alert`. About your problem, nesting emph commands should be used to over-emphasize a part of text, not to make the text back to its default level of emphasization, so defining a second emphasize command for that purpose would be a solution. In case what you want is simply to come back to the default level, the natural way of doing so is to close the macro and open a second one.

Comment: The problem is not on the use of `\em` and `\emph`. It is just for nested `\emph`s.

Comment: @JosephWright I frequently rely on nested `\emph`s.

Comment: @T.Verron Creating a second command defeats the purpose. If, for some reason, you decide to remove the top-level emphasis command, you have to change the status of the second-level command to top-level command. If the second-level command is visible, this may not be a problem and you may spot it. However, if it's the result of a macro call, you may very well not notice it.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen : That may be true, but not necessarily. If the point was to over-emphasize the second-level, removing the emphasize on the top-level sentence doesn't need to "demote" the second-level sentence.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen My point was that in a presentation it's rare to need this, plus Till is pretty clear about his view on emphasis in presentations in the manual (as T. Verron notes). That said, I don't necessarily find some of Till's decisions all that helpful, but I have to work with the situation that `beamer` is widely-used and I don't want to break things for users. (Also, it's not clear whether this was a deliberate decision or an oversight!)

Comment: I am well aware of the problems of using `\em` in a presentation, yet, that's my choice :)  Besides, the initial problem is that I am quoting an author who is using emphasis in his text, and that does not deserve `\alert` either.  Both `{quote}` and `\emph` where not behaving properly (accordingly to _my_ expectations, agreed), I fixed the first one, but missed the second.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`beamerbaseoverlay.sty` contains

> `\newcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\only#2{\itshape}#1}}`

so `\emph` only produces italic shape.  However, `\em` is not changed and you can write

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\frame{\em abc {\em def {\em ghi} jkl} mno}
\end{document}
```

giving

[image: Sample output]

which produces the shapes you expect, but is not overloaded with the overlay options `beamer` provides in its modified `\emph`.  The overlay options mean that you can write `\emph<3>{text}` to print the text on all slides but italise it only on slide 3.  If you are willing to forego this functionality and just want `\emph` to behave like `{\em ...}` then you can put

```
\renewcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\em #1}}
```

in your preamble.  *Added*: As you comment, the above may be combined to get the overlay behaviour via:

```
\renewcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\only#2{\em}#1}}
```

As other posters note, often one would prefer to use `beamer` commands such as `\alert` for extra contrast in presentations.

Comment: Thanks, I have chosen to reimplement `\emph` with `\renewcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\only#2{\em}#1}}` because (i) I _want_ `\emph` and I consider it a bug that Beamer turns the feature off without saying, and (ii), yet I want to use the <> features.