# Set color of \emph{} in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, emphasis

How can I set the color of the `\emph{}`-tag in beamer? I tried something like

`\setbeamercolor{emph}{fg=red}`

inside of `beamercolortheme.sty` but it had no effect.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `\alert{...}`?  `\emph` only italicizes the content.

Comment: In case you want it to contain colour, you can redefine it, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89435/36296

Comment: Ok, I think that's it, thanks ;-). I put `\renewcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\color{red}{\only#2{\itshape}#1}}}` inside of my `beamercolortheme.sty`

Comment: If you solved your problem, can your write an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You posted a “solution“ in the comments.  I cannot recommend changing `beamercolortheme.sty` though, because it might be overwritten once you update your system.  Also the document is no longer portable.  If you edit it on another PC or send it to a friend you'd have to include instructions on which files to edit.

Such changes usually go in the preamble of your document.  I also used the beamer color approach.  You can read more in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setbeamercolor{emph}{fg=red}
\renewcommand<>{\emph}[1]{%
  {\usebeamercolor[fg]{emph}\only#2{\itshape}#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  ABC \emph{DEG} GHI
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]